# How to allow only specific keys of an object inside a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

function: `const myFunc = (object) => //does stuff`

when I call `myFunc` I only want it to allow a valid object type so let's say I have

```
type MyType = {
   a: string
   b: number
}
```

if I do `myFunc({a: "5"})` that would be ok as would `myFunc({b: 10})` but `myFunc({c: 12})` should fail.

how do I define it so it listens to the keys?

I'm thinking I might need `keyof` or `typeof` but not sure how I use them if so

Comment: What do you mean _"specific keys"_? `myFunc = (object: Partial<MyType>) => ...`?

Comment: Is the object allowed to have more than one key like `myFunc({a: "5", b: 10})`? Or no key at all (like `myFunc({})`)? Using `Partial<MyType>` allows both of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Partial` should do it.

```
const myFunc = (object: Partial<MyType>) => //does stuff
```